How to Expand and Simplify a Complex Hamiltonian in Mathematica?
I am working on a quantum system and need to expand and simplify a Hamiltonian in Mathematica. The Hamiltonian is given as:
$$
H_{I} = \hbar \frac{\chi}{2} a_{1}^{\dagger 2} a_{1}^{2} + \left(i\hbar \frac{\kappa}{2} a_{2} a_{1}^{\dagger 2} + i\hbar \mathcal{E}_{2} a_{2}^{\dagger} + \text{H.c.} \right),
$$
which can also be written as:
$$
H_{I} = \hbar \frac{\chi}{2} a_{1}^{\dagger 2} a_{1}^{2} + \left(i\hbar \frac{\kappa}{2} a_{2} a_{1}^{\dagger 2} + i\hbar \mathcal{E}_{2} a_{2}^{\dagger} - i\hbar \frac{\kappa}{2} a_{2}^{\dagger} a_{1}^{2} - i\hbar \mathcal{E}_{2}^{*} a_{2} \right),
$$
or more compactly:
$$
H_{I} = \hbar \left(\frac{\chi}{2} a_{1}^{\dagger 2} a_{1}^{2} + i \frac{\kappa}{2} a_{2} a_{1}^{\dagger 2} + i \mathcal{E}_{2} a_{2}^{\dagger} - i \frac{\kappa}{2} a_{2}^{\dagger} a_{1}^{2} - i \mathcal{E}_{2}^{*} a_{2} \right).
$$
I would like to:

Represent this Hamiltonian in Mathematica in a form suitable for further symbolic manipulation.
Expand the terms and simplify the Hermitian conjugates (H.c.) explicitly.
Verify if the Hamiltonian is Hermitian after expansion.

Could someone guide me on how to approach this in Mathematica? Any examples or suggestions for writing operators like $a_1^\dagger$ and $a_1$ and handling their algebra would be greatly appreciated.

Feel free to adapt this to your specific needs!
